# React-Table - How to combine useResizeColumns with sticky Header in Material-UI table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-table, react-table-v7

In the latest version (7.5.x) of React-Table, is there a way to add the column resizing to a Material-UI table without breaking the 'Sticky Header' property of the Material-UI Table?

On one hand, adding 'useFlexLayout' or 'useBlockLayout' breaks the 'Sticky Header', on the other, column resizing isn't working without 'useFlexLayout' or 'useBlockLayout'...

In the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-pine-sh5ew) example, both `useBlockLayout` & `useResizeColumns` are set and the `stickyHeader` is ignored. Once `useBlockLayout` & `useResizeColumns` are commented out, the  `stickyHeader` is working again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-torvalds-zqofj?file=/src/App.js). I hope this is what you need.

I`ve added some inline styles to the elements:

```
<MaUTable
  ...
  style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}
>
<TableHead
    style={{
      position: "sticky",
      top: 0,
      alignSelf: "flex-start",
      zIndex: 1
    }}
  >
...
<TableBody style={{ position: "relative", zIndex: 0 }}>
```

Comment: THanks for your answer. Unfortunately, in your codesandbox, the table header doesn't resize together with the table (try making the table wider)